# Vuejs open/toggle single item

Tags: vue.js, toggle, each

I work with single file components and have a list in one of them. This list should work like a accordion, but as far as I can find in the Vuejs docs, it's not that easy to make each item open separately very easily. The data (questions and answers) is retrieved from an ajax call. I use jQuery for that, but would like to know how I can make the accordion work Vuejs-style. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the code:

```js
export default {
  name: 'faq-component',
  props: ['faqid', 'faqserviceurl', 'ctx'],
  data: function () {
    return {
     showFaq: "",
     totalFaqs: this.data,
     isOpen: true
     }
  },
  watch: {   
  'showFaq': function(val, faqid, faqserviceurl) {
   var self = this;
   $.ajax ({
             url: this.faqserviceurl,
             type: 'GET',
             data: {id: this.faqid, q: val, scope:1},
             success: function (data) { 
                self.totalFaqs = data; 
             },
             error: function () {
              $("#answer").html('Sorry');
             }    
   });
   }
  },
  methods: {
   'toggle': function() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
    
   }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<template>
 <div class="card faq-block">  
  <div class="card-block">  
   <form>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your question" id="faq" v-model="showFaq">
    </div>
   </form>  
   
   <div id="answer"></div>  
   <ul class="faq">
    <li v-for="faq in totalFaqs">
     <p class="question" v-html="faq.vraag" v-bind:class={open:isOpen} @click="isOpen = !isOpen"></p>
     <p class="answer" v-html="faq.antwoord"></p>
    </li>
   </ul>     
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `isOpen` property to each object in `totalFaqs` and use that instead of your single `isOpen` property in data.

```
<p class="question" v-html="faq.vraag" v-bind:class={open: faq.isOpen} @click="faq.isOpen = !faq.isOpen"></p>
```

If you can't change the model from the server side, then add it client side.

```
success: function (data) {
  data.forEach(d => self.$set(d, 'isOpen', false)) 
  self.totalFaqs = data 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Ended up using the client side as well. Works like a charm.